# com.sun.j3d.utils.universe "does not exist" after successfully installing Java3D

Tags: java, java-3d

I successfully installed Java3D on Windows 7, using the installation executable obtained from [here](https://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html),  and am building an application on NetBeans 7.4.  I have also included j3d-core-1.3.1.jar into my project.

The call

```
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.*;
```

still results in the message

```
com.sun.j3d.utils.universe does not exist
```

Comment: The `...Java3D\1.5.1\lib\ext` directory should also contain a `j3dutils.jar` - it's contained in this one.

Comment: Wrong location, rather look at that: http://tinyurl.com/cf47kcb You're still using an abandoned version of Java 3D provided by Oracle. Please never put your JARs into /lib/ext in order to avoid conflicts.